# Using Expo React Native, is there any way to run a stopwatch / timer in the background?

Tags: react-native, expo

**Problem**

I've created a simple stopwatch app using Expo for React Native. When I leave the app (click the home button on iPhone), and return to the app, the stopwatch starts back up from the time when I left. For example, if the stopwatch is at 3 seconds and I leave the app for 5 seconds, when I return it is still at 3 seconds rather than 8.

**Question**

Using Expo, is there any way to run the stopwatch in the background? If yes, how? If no, what is the best workaround?

**Resources**

I've found similar questions that are dated, but I'm looking for something recent. Some of the resources mentioned in the other answers are the following:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/background-fetch/
- https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your best bet is to note the start time and persist it, e.g. using Expo's [AsyncStorage](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/). Then you can just display the time elapsed since this stored start time.